# Populate Choicebox defined in FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm learning **javaFX** and my problem is that I have simple window with some choicebox and button. This window is defined via FXML which is also associated with controller class.
I would like to know, how to populate this choicebox with data in the controller class, because using @FXML reference to this choicebox throws`NullpointerEception`

**EDIT - added source code**
FXML code

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="240.0"
        prefWidth="320.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="supermarket.ManageWindowCC">
<children>
    <ChoiceBox fx:id="countChoiceBox" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="191.0"/>
    <Label layoutX="44.0" layoutY="54.0" text="To change item's count, choose one"/>
    <TextField layoutX="140.0" layoutY="129.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="24.0"/>
    <Label layoutX="123.0" layoutY="112.0" text="New count"/>
    <Button layoutX="126.1875" layoutY="171.5" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Submit"/>
</children>
```

Java controller code:

```
public class ManageWindowCC {
@FXML
private ChoiceBox countChoiceBox;

public void onChangeCountClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ChangeCount.fxml"));
        Stage newStage = new Stage();
        newStage.setTitle("Change item's count");
        newStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 320, 240));
        newStage.show();
        countChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox();
        countChoiceBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One","Two","Three"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Thank you fro your help and time

Comment: Please edit your question and add some code, e.g. the fxml and the Controller class, where you referenced the Choicebox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to fix it**

Remove the line `countChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox();` and everything will work fine, assuming you have no other bugs elsewhere in your application.

The program will use the reference to the countChoiceBox which is part of the node hierarchy created by the FXMLLoader and set in your scene.

**What is happening**

Loading a new FXML in `onChangeCountClick` will:

1. Create a new `supermarket.ManageWindowCC` controller.
2. Create a hierarchy of Nodes based upon the FXML definition.
3. One of the nodes in the hierarchy will be a ChoiceBox.
4. The ChoiceBox *which the FXML loader automatically creates for you* will be assigned to the countChoiceBox member.
5. You then take the hierarchy of nodes assigned to root and add it to your new Scene on your new Stage.

So, after you load the FXML, countChoiceBox is initialized to an empty ChoiceBox instantiated by your FXMLLoader

This is all fine so far . . .

What you then do is (incorrectly) write:

```
countChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox();
```

The rule of thumb you violate is => never use `new` to assign a value to a members tagged `@FXML`.

---

Also see the somewhat related example for [populating a ComboBox using FXML](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3062859) (though that sample uses a ComboBox and populates its data directly in FXML, so it is not directly applicable to your situation).

Comment: Thank you for your really smart explanation. Now I know that this code should work. The exception is still there, but as you mentioned, there has to be some other bug in the rest of the controller class. 
I haven't understood the all mechanisms and relations between windows yet. To be more specific: this window should be shown after clicking to a button placed in another stage but these stages share the same `ManageWindowCC` controller. Som maybe that's the reason of the Nullpointer exception

Comment: Generally, if you create an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which contains complete, standalone code that somebody could compile and execute without modification, it is an effective way in getting help and ensuring that your program works as desired.

Comment: Last few hours I was searching stackowerflow and I've found your professional answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)
You are the best. I've finally understood how to pass arguments between controllers
Thank you very very much :)

Answer (score 2):

@using FXML
STEP 1: Add a choice box in the scene builder and call it maybe(choiceBox)
STEP 2: IN the controller add the following codes
    @FXML
  private  ChoiceBox choiceBox ;

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
 ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   list.addAll("choice1", "choice2","choice3");
  //populate the Choicebox;  
  choiceBox .setItems(list);

}
```