# Javafx - how to modify components in fxml file after loading it

Tags: javafx

I am a novice to javafx. I created a simple javafx fxml application. I defined a treeView in my fxml file. It is as follows,

### FXMLDocument.fxml

```
 <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="320.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="scenebuilderfirst.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
     <TreeView id="" fx:id="tree" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="172.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
 </AnchorPane>
```

and created the controller class as follows,

### FXMLDocumentController.java

```
 public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

     @FXML
     private TreeView<?> tree;   

     @Override
     public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

     }    
 }
```

my main java file is as follows,

### MyApp.java

```
 public class SceneBuilderFirst extends Application {

     @Override
     public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
         AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

         Scene scene = new Scene(root);

         stage.setScene(scene);
         stage.show();

     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
     }    
 }
```

Now I need to add tree items to the TreeView while running the program. So I thought of writing the following peace of code inside the initialize() method of my contorller class,

```
    // creating root item for the tree
    TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>("root");
    rootItem.setExpanded(true);
    //creating childern for the tree
    TreeItem<String>item1= new TreeItem<>("content1");
    rootItem.getChildren().add(item1);
    TreeItem<String>item2= new TreeItem<>("content2");
    rootItem.getChildren().add(item2);

    //attaching root item to tree
    tree = new TreeView<>(rootItem);
```

But it didn't work.

**I need to set the TreeItems while running the program. Not through the fxml file.**
So I think I should do the coding in my main java file
**I need a way to access my TreeView after loading it via FXMLLoader** in my main java file so i can make a TreeView on my own choice and attach it to this TreeView while running the program. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, replace

```
tree = new TreeView<>(rootItem);
```

with

```
tree.setRoot(rootItem);
```

For an explanation of why, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067256/populate-choicebox-defined-in-fxml/).

You also have to fix your declaration of the `TreeView`:

```
@FXML
private TreeView<String> tree;
```